# How to select specific data in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I have a sample program that use Core Data and load an sqlite database in it. And I am displaying all the values using this code

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Name"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (Name *name in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"ID: %@", name.nameId);
    NSLog(@"First Name: %@", name.first);
    NSLog(@"Middle Name: %@", name.middle);
    NSLog(@"Last Name: %@", name.last);
}
```

This code works fine, my problem here is that I can't select a specific data/record. Example I want to select the record with the ID = 1.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check down the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use predicates (with NSPredicate) before your request execution.

Something like that :

```
NSPredicate *predicateID = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nameID == %d",-1];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicateID];
```

Answer (score 10):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Name"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

//Add following method to your code. this will help you to get desired result.
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"yourColumnID == %@", yourID]];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (Name *name in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"ID: %@", name.nameId);
    NSLog(@"First Name: %@", name.first);
    NSLog(@"Middle Name: %@", name.middle);
    NSLog(@"Last Name: %@", name.last);
}
```